# Change Ubuntu one and one-conf sync account

Tags: ubuntu-one, oneconf

I've made a mistake and created a second account in Ubuntu SSO with my new email account and now I want to change it from the one-conf and from my Ubuntu one account. I can't find where to change the account in neither apps. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu One, go to the control panel, the devices tab, then remove the current device.

Before you login with the new account you will have to remove the metadata to avoid a root_mismatch error. This means deleting ~/.cache/ubuntuone

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, it is ~/.local/share/ubuntuone where the metadata lives.